# vuejs v-html image tag not resolving src

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a vue page which uses `v-html` to place an html content inside a `<div>` as follows:

```
<div v-html="noDataMessage">               
</div>
```

And the data of `noDataMessage` is set in `created()` lifecycle hook of vue.

```
created() {  
   this.noDataMessage = "<img src='../assets/Content/img/Myfav_empty.png' width='35px' height='35px'>";
}
```

The html tag is showing properly, but it is not able to fetch the image.
I tried to load the image separately to see if image path is correct, and got the image.

Am I missing anything particular to vue.js or v-html in particular?

Comment: If you look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/491013/) it seems to work fine. I think the issue is in fact in your path.
Edit: Perhaps take a look [at this link](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/v-binding-an-image-from-an-object-to-an-img-src-not-working-in-vue-pwa-template/12754) which might solve your issue

Comment: Look in your browser console's network tab to see if the request for the image is being made or not, and if it is, whether it's failing due to a 404 error, in which case, as the previous commenter suggested, your path would be wrong

Comment: Instead of this path `../assets/Content/img/Myfav_empty.png`, try this one `@/assets/Content/img/Myfav_empty.png`, or this one `~@/assets/Content/img/Myfav_empty.png`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is in the src **url** you are using, the src url root is the public directory.

For example, if you have all your images in public->images directory then your code will look like this:

```
this.noDataMessage = "<img src='images/Myfav_empty.png' width='35px' height='35px'>";
```

Comment: This has solved the issue. But I wonder, what would someone do if relative path is to be specified?

Comment: Could you tell me an example to the relative path you want, because if the relative path is outside the public directory then it won't work with this way.

Answer (score 0):

It seems perfect only.

I have implemented the same way to fetch the image, Here I can see the image.
Please check the path once again.

You can check below example where I have tried to implement same way
`:`http://jsfiddle.net/suprabhasupi/eywraw8t/491005/