# vue/cli renaming images unable to access

Tags: image, vue-cli

I can easily add an image on any component like this:
`<img src="@/images/q3.png">` but when I see the devtools the src has a different name `<img src="/img/q3.91066fb2.png">`. The vue/cli adds the image to a diferent folder and it adds a random number to the name. The problem is that I need to use the image inside a v-html as a text: `v-html='<img src="@/images/q3.png">'`(the text is inside a variable in data, this is just a simplification) but this doesn't work showing a blanck image. What can I do to access this image?

Ps: I have multiple images, I need a solution that works with all of them

Edit: I find this possible duplicate: [vuejs v-html image tag not resolving src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53627981/vuejs-v-html-image-tag-not-resolving-src/53628289). It helps me see that the problem is the path. So I changed the images folder to be alongside the src and public folders and i changed the path to `<img src="images/q3.png">` and it worked. Though I don't know if this is best practice, could not make the images folder inside the public or src folders.

Edit: As suggested I can just move the images folder into the public folder while remain with the same path images/q3.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm thinking you could create a method that would load the image *content* (not path) and place *that* directly into the dynamic HTML. Something like so:

```
new Vue({
    methods: {
        generateImg(path) {
            let img = require(path);
            return '<img src="' + img + '">'
        }
    }
}
```

So you'd call `generateImg("@/images/q3.png")` and place the returned value in your v-html. You can reuse this for other images.

I haven't tested this, but would it work for you?

--

Alternatively, if you place the images in the `public` directory, you should be able to access them without require.

So let's say all the images are in `public/images`. Now the path to `q3.png` will be `yoursite.com/images/q3.png`, as the files in public are not dynamically generated (so there will be no random number like 91066fb2 that vue adds to it), but you can just use `images/q3.png` within your code.

More here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53628289

Comment: I'm using v-html because i also have some text and tags along side the image, I could generate the image first and put it inside the html content with some string methods, but I think it would add so much complexity like + 80 lines of code, sorry for not being specific

Comment: I see. What if you place the images in the public dir? Check my edited answer

Comment: Thank you, this solve the problem. Should I delete my question? Because I just misunderstood the dupllicate.

Comment: I think it would be better to flag it as a duplicate. I'll do that